# How to convert normal html website home page to SharePoint master page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: master-page

I follow some article to convert HTML page to master page and I stocked in snipped section. After converting, my HTML page and other design are rendered in above section of master page and SharePoint header part are rendered in below section. And I don't know how to use these HTML design with my SharePoint nav bar and quick launch and other controls so that it looks like same my HTML page.

Answer (score -1):

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822370.aspx)   for converting a HTML file to a MasterPage